# Can't install JSON gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I need to install json because I get this error:

`Could not find json-1.4.6 in any of the sources`

I ran `gem install json` and `bundle install` but I was only able to install json-1.5.1 when I need json-1.4.6

I have `gem 'json', '1.4.6'` in my gemfile, so I'm not sure what's going on...

UPDATE

I get this error:

Installing json (1.4.6) /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1216:in `chmod': Operation not permitted - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.4.6/CHANGES (Errno::EPERM)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why did you run `gem install json` at all? Bundler takes care of that for you and will ensure that the correct version of each gem is installed (since sometimes dependencies require an older version). Run

```
gem uninstall json
bundle install
```

Also ensure you have `source 'https://rubygems.org'` at the top of your Gemfile.

As for the permissions info, you may have to run `gem` and `bundle` commands with `sudo`.

By the way, I **highly** recommend taking a look at and using [RVM](https://rvm.io), particularly the [gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets) feature. It will make your life infinitely better when developing Ruby apps. If you decide to do so, I'd also suggest trashing all the gems you've install using the system Ruby by running `sudo rm -rf /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/`. It's also important that when using RVM you don't have to use `sudo` when running `gem` (or `bundle`), which is not only safer but less typing too.

Comment: Ok I did that. I have `source 'http://rubygems.org` at the top. I still get this error: `Could not find json-1.4.6 in any of the sources`

Comment: Are you running `bundle install` with or without `sudo`?

Comment: with, check the question again, I added more information on the install error

Comment: Okay, try running `sudo gem uninstall json` again, make sure that `gem list` doesn't show it being installed. Then `sudo rm -rf /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.4.6/`. Then try `sudo bundle install` again.

Comment: btw, check out this problem of mine if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215552/jquery-ajax-rendering-of-a-new-post-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Glad that worked. Definitely take a look at the last paragraph in my updated answer. RVM can be a life-saver.

Comment: I don't see why running `bundle install` would work and `gem install <gem>` wouldn't. This is not explained.

Comment: @matija Because the OP’s Gemfile specifies an older version of JSON. Running `bundle install` ensure that the correct version is installed. If you read through the comments you will also get more information, but I’ve updated the answer with that info.

Answer (score 10):

After checking logs by running $ heroku logs

I found "An error occurred while installing json (1.4.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.4.6'` succeeds before bundling."

I then removed 2 json entries from the Gemfile.lock and had no further issues.

Answer (score 8):

Please update your rubygems by executing the following command..

```
gem update --system
```

may be it will solve the problem. After updating your gem. Then run the following command to install json

```
gem install json
```

Now you can get json gem installed in your system.

Comment: Did the job for me, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try:
$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rbenv, try `rbenv rehash`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to build a website with Jekyll.

Turned out I hadn't followed all the instructions at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/ubuntu/

I don't know if it was the missing packages or commands into ~/.bashrc but it fixed the problem in two instances of Ubuntu in WSL

Answer (score -2):

Remove the json entries from the Gemfile.lock file and try to re run bundle install..