# Can't install json gem 1.8.6 - failed to build gem native extension on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ubuntu, bundler

Bundler on Ubuntu 16.04 yields the following error when trying to install JSON.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /tmp/bundler20170601-12986-10dsu07json-1.8.6/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170601-12986-op73sp.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20170601-12986-10dsu07json-1.8.6/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20170601-12986-10dsu07json-1.8.6/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  react-rails was resolved to 1.7.2, which depends on
    rails was resolved to 4.2.7.1, which depends on
      actionmailer was resolved to 4.2.7.1, which depends on
        actionpack was resolved to 4.2.7.1, which depends on
          actionview was resolved to 4.2.7.1, which depends on
            rails-dom-testing was resolved to 1.0.8, which depends on
              rails-deprecated_sanitizer was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
                activesupport was resolved to 4.2.7.1, which depends on
                  json
```

It looks as if the gem extensions couldn't be compiled because of lacking header files. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there is [similar problem on RedHat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216278/cant-install-json-gem).

In case of Ubuntu, the solution seems to be installing `ruby-dev` package.

`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`