# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension for rails version 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have created new rails app and try to run **bundle install** it shows this error,

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170704-11395-12tpg5u.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling
```

Kindly send me some suggestions,Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what happens when you do `gem install json -v '1.8.6'`

Comment: It shows this error
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have a Mac or Linux machine try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

If that fails, what is your output for:

```
gem install json -v '1.8.6'
```

(please copy and paste all the output).

[Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216278/cant-install-json-gem)

I'm not sure what will fix it for Mac, but people had positive experiences with `brew install ruby`.

Comment: apt-get doesn't work in Mac out of the box. Maybe add brew version of this too?

Comment: @rentedrainbow I can't replicate this on my Mac, do you know what you need to install with brew?

Comment: Yes, did `brew install ruby` and then it worked again on macOS.

Comment: I didn't encounter that on my Mac but I posted @appsunited's suggestion just in case it will help people.

Comment: this is the error l am getting: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"

Answer (score 3):

If anyone facing this error with Mac OS Big Sur, please update the ruby version to atleast 2.7. I am using rvm to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First checked the **ruby** version and **rvm** list
if **rvm** not install then install **rvm**

Comment: Could you provide a bit more clarity about the commands to run?

Comment: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/nginx/oss/install_language_runtime.html

Comment: Follow this full guide to how to install rails on linux: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-1404/